# How to find records that are not present in spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office-2016

I have two spreadsheet in Excel file more than 100000 data, Account spreadsheet and premium spreadsheet. I need to find out duplicate data which is present in premium spreadsheet that are not present in Account spreadsheet.

Comment: Is there any kind of unique identifier that you can use to tell the records apart? Do you expect there to be many (>100) records overlapping or only a few? What will you do with the duplicate data after you find it?

Comment: So there is already duplicate values in Account Sheet? And from the duplicate values you want to find out if they exist in Premium Sheet?

Comment: I have UniqueCustomerId in both spreadsheet Account and premium. Account premium sheet may contains duplicate uniquecustomerid and i need to check that premium spreadsheet has contains or not uniquecustomerid that are not present in account spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I need to check that premium spreadsheet has contains or not uniquecustomerid that are not present in account spreadsheet"*

If your goal is only to see which value from `Premium!` allready exists on `Account!` then use something like:

[image]

[image]

Formula in `Premium!B2`:

```
=COUNTIF(Account!A:A,A2)>0
```